# How to save an image locally from flask request?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am getting an image using this HTML template:

```
<div class="ml-container">
    <form action="{{ url_for("predict")}}" method="post">
        <span>Upload your image here</span>
        <input name="Select File" type="file" name="get_image">
        <input type="submit" class="my-cta-button" value="Click here to predict caption"> 
    </form>
 </div>
```

I want to save this image in `static/file.jpg` folder in my directory using Flask. I am using this code to save it.

```
@app.route('/predict', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    image = request.form.get('get_image')
    image.save('static/file.jpg')
    caption = greedySearch((encode('static/file.jpg').reshape((1, 2048))))
    
    return render_template('index.html', prediction = caption)
```

But, it's not working and showing this error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2022 12:17:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2022-05-15 12:17:20,170] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "<ipython-input-5-ac464086eb60>", line 46, in predict
    image.save('static/file.jpg')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2022 12:17:20] "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

How do I save that image in `static` folder?

Comment: `image = request.form.get('get_image')`  ... does the *image* variable actually contain an image? ... if not, then perhaps you should be asking how to receive an uploaded file before you ask how to save it

Answer (score 0):

In your flask app you must change the controller like below:

```py
@app.route('/predict', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    image = flask.request.files['get_image']
    image.save('static/file.jpg')
    caption = greedySearch((encode('static/file.jpg').reshape((1, 2048))))
    
    return render_template('index.html', prediction = caption)
```

If you import the request directly:

```py
from flask import request
```

then edit the part of code which read image file in this way:

```py
image = request.files['get_image']
```

And in your html code block you specified the name attribute twice.

```html
<div class="ml-container">
    <form action="{{ url_for("predict")}}" method="post">
        <span>Upload your image here</span>
        <input type="file" name="get_image">
        <input type="submit" class="my-cta-button" value="Click here to predict caption"> 
    </form>
 </div>
```